# Akka with Scala IDE

Tags: scala, ide, akka, configuration-files

I'm trying to create an Akka project using the Scala ide (Windows 7). I created a Scala project and then I imported the Akka jars I downloaded. Simple projects work fine, but now I want to change the mailbox of an actor to a priority mailbox, but I can't find any "application.conf" file. Is there a way to do this with just the Scala IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new file `application.conf` and place it under `src/main/resources` directory.